Nmap showing open ports althought nftables is configured to drop
On a fresh Debian 12 install, I have the following nftables configuration that I believe does the following when activated:

traffic from localhost accepted
established/related traffic accepted
TCP traffic via port 22 accepted

#!/usr/sbin/nft -f

flush ruleset

table inet filter {
        chain input {
                type filter hook input priority 0; policy drop;

                # accept any localhost traffic
                iifname lo accept

                # accept traffic originated from us
                ct state established,related accept

                tcp dport 22 accept
        }

        chain forward {
                # Drop everything (assumes this device is not a router)                  
                type filter hook forward priority 0; policy drop;
        }
}

Note that to switch from configuration with rules to the one without rules, I first systemctl restart nftables, and then verify the rules being applied with nft list ruleset.
Consider the case with rules applied, I expect nmap to show only port 22 to be open. However, I get the following:
$ nmap <DEBIAN12_IP_ADDRESS>
Starting Nmap 7.92 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2024-10-17 10:46 CEST
Nmap scan report for <DEBIAN12_HOSTNAME> (<DEBIAN12_IP_ADDRESS>)
Host is up (0.043s latency).
Not shown: 990 filtered tcp ports (no-response)
PORT     STATE SERVICE
21/tcp   open  ftp
22/tcp   open  ssh
80/tcp   open  http
82/tcp   open  xfer
84/tcp   open  ctf
85/tcp   open  mit-ml-dev
443/tcp  open  https
554/tcp  open  rtsp
1723/tcp open  pptp
5060/tcp open  sip

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 8.25 seconds

Is the nftables configuration not doing what I think it does?
Is it me not understanding what nmap outputs?

Is your machine behind some provider's router that does have those ports open?

All my connections goes through a 4G LTE Router.

Any idea @Kusalananda?

Yes, if you are running nmap against your public IP, then you might see open ports on routers that sit between you and the Internet (routers that you have no control over). This is basically restating my initial comment.
